# SQL/SQLite retrieve list of devices belonging to users when users and devices are stored in same table with associations stored in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, recursion

Another case of being given a poorly designed, quite old database and told to extract useful information from it. I do speak a very little bit of SQL but this exceeds my knowledge. I quite frankly hit a wall.

So I've been given an SQLite DB which contains several tables. Of interest are the tables **nodes** and **associations**.

Table **nodes** contains all elements such as users, devices (which are PCs) but a whole lot more such as desk phone apparatus, office numbers, operating systems, basically everything and anything. Here a sample:

```
id       title          entity_type
-----------------------------------
1        user1          User
2        user2          User
3        pc1            Device
4        user3          User
5        pc2            Device
6        pc3            Device
7        pc4            Device
8        os1            OS
9        phon1          Phone
10       os2            OS
11       phon2          Phone
11       phon3          Phone
```

Table **associations** maps a device to a user, but also contains a LOT more garbage mappings, such as operating systems to PCs, phones to offices, etc.

```
id       parent         child
-----------------------------
1        3              1
2        5              2
3        6              4
4        7              4
5        3              8
6        5              8
7        6              10
```

So **associations** maps pc1 with user1, pc2 with user2, pc3 and pc4 with user3 but also os1 to pc1 and pc2, os2 to pc3 etc.
Thankfully **users only have PCs**, no other items are mapped to users.

I was asked to compile a list which shows all PCs and which user they are assigned to. Basically I need to get:

```
user1     pc1
user2     pc2
user3     pc3
user3     pc4
```

My idea was along the lines of:

```sql
SELECT nodes.id,title,parent
  FROM nodes
  INNER JOIN associations ON nodes.id = associations.child
  WHERE entity_type = "User"
  ORDER BY id;
```

So far, this gives me a list of all users and the **parents** (e.g. the PCs ID in nodes) which belong to them. I have no clue though how I could replace the parent, which right now is just a number refering to the ID in nodes, with the title of this item.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use multiple joins to the same table - something like:

```
select user.title as user, pc.title as pc
from nodes as user
join associations as a on a.child=user.id
join nodes as pc on a.parent=pc.id
where user.entity_type = 'User'
```

Regarding the "parent+1 for notebooks" logic mentioned in the comments: If I understand correctly, when a PC's title is "mobile", it's a notebook, and the node with the next id is the real title.

```
select user.title as user, ifnull(nb.title, pc.title) as computer
from nodes as user
join associations as a on a.child=user.id
join nodes as pc on a.parent=pc.id
left join nodes as nb on pc.title='mobile' and nb.id = pc.id + 1
where user.entity_type = 'User'
```

Using a `left join` means that `nb` fields will all be `null` in the case that the pc title is *not* 'mobile', and populated when it is. The `ifnull` in the `select` should ensure the correct title is used for each row.

Comment: Many thanks, the resulting table is _almost_ perfect.

Comment: No problem - did you manage to tweak it to actual perfection?

Comment: Argh... Enter sent the comment where I meant it to insert a line break. Here's the full comment:

Many thanks, the resulting table is _almost_ perfect.

Checking the results, I found that Notebooks as opposed to PCs apparently have two entries in **nodes** following each other. So for PC's, it's parent=id, for Notebooks it's parent+1=id.
parent=id Notebooks the `title` is "mobile" and parent+1 is "Notebook1".

Could this condition (e.g. `where title="mobile"`) be accounted for and instead of title for parent=id output title for parent+1=id?

Comment: Yuck. But yes, that should be do-able. See my edit for an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query that will extract all user to node relations.  It doesn't assume that users are only ever the child node:

```
select u.title, n.entity_type, n.title
  from nodes u
  join associations a
    on u.id in (a.parent, a.child)
  join nodes n
    on n.id <> u.id
   and n.id in (a.parent, a.child)
 where u.entity_type = 'User'
```